# Pass a list of directories to rsync

Tags: rsync, backup

I have a text file `list_of_dirs_to_copy` with 120 paths:

```
data/A/backups/2018_02_12
data/B/backups/2/files
data/B/old_files/2015_12
data/C/my_datafiles/800/dat
data/F/backups & old files (second backups)
...
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: line breaks are `LF` in the file above and there are special characters such as `&` and `(` in directory names.

`data` is located in `/mnt/storage3/workfiles/backups`. So I do `cd /mnt/storage3/workfiles/backups` so that paths in my `list_of_dirs_to_copy` become relevant.

Now I want to copy all of the directories listed in my text file (with all of their hidden files and sub-directories) to another hard drive using the following command.

```
rsync -rvh --append-verify --chmod=ugo=rwX --no-o --no-g --no-perms --progress --stats $list_of_directories /drives/f/data_backups/
```

How can I pass the list of directories to `rsync` without breaking it (i.e. receiving `Argument list too long`)? Would it be possible to send each line of the text to `rsync` one by one? Would that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

```
rsync -av ...options... --files-from=list_of_dirs_to_copy \
    /mnt/storage3/workfiles/backups/ \
    /drives/f/data_backups
```

The paths in `list_of_dirs_to_copy` would be interpreted as being relative to the source directory.  With the given list, this would create `data` as a subdirectory under `/drives/f/data_backups`.

Comment: This is most probably caused by my `rsync` (I am using `MobaXterm`) which leads me to an error when I use the `--files-from` tag. So I instead opted for: `while read -r COPYPATHS; do rsync -R -rvh --append-verify --chmod=ugo=rwX --no-o --no-g --no-perms --progress --stats "$COPYPATHS" /drives/f/data_backups; done < /home/files/list_of_dirs_to_copy.txt`. This no longer produces an error.

Comment: The error I am receiving is: `Use "rsync --daemon --help" to see the daemon-mode command-line options. Please see the rsync(1) and rsyncd.conf(5) man pages for full documentation. See http://rsync.samba.org/ for updates, bug reports, and answers rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/options.c(1653) [client=3.0.9]`

Comment: @benett Huh? I hope you replaced my "...options..." placeholder with your actual options.